# How do you interpret the region $\sqrt{y} \leq x \leq 2$?

Tags: complex-numbers, notation

Are the statements $i \le -1$ and $-i \le -1$ defined as false?  I was trying to determine a region $D$ given by $\sqrt{y} \le x \le 2$ and wasn't sure how to interpret points like $(-1,-1)$. Is it obvious that they should be excluded? [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csqrt%7By%7D+%3C%3D+x+%3C%3D+2) seems to think so.

Comment: $y$ cannot be negative in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, you could ask yourself what is the Domain of the square root function in this case; well, since x is a real number that must be greater than $\sqrt{y}$, this square root cannot admit negative real numbers as argument, since that would imply that $x$ would have to be greater than a complex number and that just does not make sense.
Just pointing out that that the domain of your function is adapted to the problem in case, and you *do* want it to be $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: Oh!! I had forgotten that the square-root always must be positive...

Answer (score 3):

Here is meant the region in the real plane.
$i \le -1$ makes no sense because complex number has no order.

Comment: Do you mean that since $x$ and $y$ are real, then the statement $i \le -1$ is false? OR do you mean that if $x$ and $y$ are real, then $\sqrt{-1} \neq \pm i$? Cause if $\sqrt{-1} = i$ then the statement $i \le -1$ must be evaluated to either true or false.

Comment: No, the statement $i\le -1$ cannot be evaluated at all because there is no order in the field of complex numbers. The statement is meaningless because the operator $\le$ is not defined on complex numbers.

Comment: As a general principle, whenever you see a formula like $0<x$ or $5<y<6$ there is a connotation that the variables are real valued

Comment: @Logic_Problem_42 So logically: since they say that $\sqrt{y} \le x$ *is true*, then it can't be undefined (by comparing complex numbers)?

Comment: You have really funny logic. :) Why do You think that all concepts from real numbers can be transferred to complex numbers? This is essentially wrong.